# <quality> even for being a <noun>

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, word-comparison

Salvēte omnēs, hocc erit mihi prīmum rogātum hāc in sēde. Haud dūdum vīdī quendam hominem scīscitārī, quōmodo posset Latīnē dīcī "he has a long tail, even for a cat". Ad quod rogātum cum respondēre cōnātus sum, prōtinus appāruit rem vix liquēre nec mihi, nec cēterīs sodālibus - id quod prīmum in buccam vēnerat, vidēlicet "prō fēle", nūsquam repperī nec dīcī posse conclūdō. Dēnique vīsum est sīc dīcī: *"longa cōda eī est, **etiam ut** fēlī"*. Ecce quaedam exempla quae invēnī ad hunc ūsum confirmandum:

> - Archelāus, physicus, **ut** est captus antīquitātis, dīligens (SenPhil.Nat.6.12)
> - satis exercitātum in dīcendō, **ut** Thebanum **scīlicet** (Nep.Vit.Ep.5.2)
> - (ōrātiōnis genus) **ut** in ōrātore, exīle, inūsitātum (Cic.deOrat.3.66)

Item cētera utputa *"ut illīs temporibus, ut tum rēs erant"*. Alius sodālis prōposuit *"vel/etsī prout fēlēs"* - atquī ego exempla cum *"prout"* nōn reperiō nisi cum verbō, igitur plēnō ōrātiōnis membrō (quod Anglicē "clause"), nec cāsus "fēlēs" cum sententiā congruere vidētur - quō colligō sīc nōn dīcī posse. *"Prout fēlēs est"* sit grammaticē dictum, tamen valeat "according to how much of a cat he is" sīve "inasmuch as".

Quod ad *"**vel**"* et *"**etiam**"*, quōrum, licet prīmō obtūtū haud prāvē dicta videantur, nūllum docvmentum repperī nisi illud parum consentāneum utpote per oppositiōnem dictum, *"vel ut"* autem plānē aliud valet:

> - vīcīna sunt haec, etiam ut dissimilia, paria vīribus, etiam ut mente dissentiant (Quint.DeclMaior.4.17.16)

Quid sī *"**ut** fēlī **quoque**"*? *"**ut vel** fēlī?"* Praetereā invēnī tālem ūsum cum modō conjūnctīvō, quī vēritātem nisi autumet, concēdit tamen:

> - vērum **ut** ita **sit**, tamen nōn potes quasi praeclārum aliquid praedicāre[...] cum[...] (Cic.Ver.2.3.151)
> - **nē sit** summum malum dolor, certē malum est (Cic. Tusc. 2, 5, 14)

Itaque certior fierī velim utrum satis liqueat tālis sententia: *"**Sit** fēlēs, longam **tamen** cōdam habet"* vel membrīs retroāctīs (*"habet..sit"*). Huic, quō clārius oppositiō exprimerētur, putāvī adjiciendam quendam particulam conjūnctiōnemve corrōborātīvam - sed haud sciō an ūlla hārum valeat "suprā spem", "granted", neque "contrā spem", "even if". Quam hārum putātis potissvmum convenīre?

- etiamsī sit fēlēs (crēdō erit "contrā")
- quamvīs sit fēlēs (crēdō erit "however much")
- tametsī sit fēlēs (dubium)
- licet sit fēlēs (dubium)
- scīlicet sit fēlēs (haud sciō an conveniat)
- fēlēs sānē sit (vidētur convenīre)
- sit quidem fēlēs (nesciō)

---

Ut reī longiusculae summam faciam: quōmodo potest efferrī, quod aliquid in suō genere ēmineat et quālitāte quādam praeditum sit suprā spem et extrā ōrdinem, imprīmīs sī ōrdō iste per sē aliquantus? Ecce exempla Anglicē:

- "he has a long tail even for a cat"
- "she's pale even for someone who's lived in a crypt for 200 years"
- "it moved quickly even for a meteor"

Comment: Salve! Iucundissimum est sodalem novum apud nos accipere, et Latine scribentem quidem. Spero aliquem tibi respondere posse necnon me ipsum plura a te scripta hic lecturum esse.

Comment: Salūtō tē ad hoc rogātōrium, Russice! Haec prīma est magna quaestiō, et quamquam ipse respōnsum rēctum nesciō, ut aliquis respondeat spērō item, sīcut Joonas!

Comment: Havēte amīcī, tum vetus tum nove! Juvat tam cōmiter hīc accipī! Est ut dīcis Ethan, putāvī nihil esse quīn continuō ad māla pervenīrem :D Nōn minus expectō mē et aliīs quoad valeō auxiliī latūrum, et ipse nōnnihil ab iīs discitūrum. Brevī vidēbō ut plūra rogam quae vel jam in animō volūtō, vel sī quid novī in buccam venit. Ut vērum autem comfitear, illud rogātum impraesentiārum mihi valdē velim dēliquētur!

Comment: Unbrutal_Russian: What do you believe "etiamsi sit feles" means? In my elementary text on concessive clauses (Oulton): "etsi (etiamsi) laetus es/ sis" = "even if you are/ were to be happy". Therefore, "etiamsi sit feles" = "even if he may be a cat".

Comment: @tony "even if he may be a cat" is what I think it means, the problem being that I'm not sure whether the implication is the downplaying "you wouldn't expect cats to such have long tails" or the admiring "you'd expect them to have long tails, but not *that* long". I was looking to express the latter meaning.

Answer (score 4):

Tibi ob rogatum tam polito sermone expressum gratias ago, etsi plene respondere nequere mihi videor.

Ut breviter viam qua opportune hanc comparationem reddere possis suggeram: omnes orationes quas proponis mihi videntur commune habere vitium, scilicet quia, licet praecellentiam quamdam in aliquo genere satis indicent, carent illa significatione in littera Anglica (ut credo) latente qua innuitur superius genus *iam* in aliquo praecellere, et excluso casu qui nunc consideratur. Omnes fere orationes antepositae ("etiamsi sit," "quamvis sit," etc.) vim habent aliquantulo dissimilem "concessivam" (ut ita dicam), velut si mirum sit potius *hunc felem habere codam longam* quam *hunc felem habere codam longiorem aliis felibus (iam longas codas habentibus!).*

Nescio an sit idonea coniunctio vel particula quae valeat hoc significare sine mediantibus verbis vel quadam mutatione orationis. Si opus esset mihi hoc reddere Latine nec valde constringerer ad ordinem Anglicae orationis servandum, aliquid huiusmodi proponerem:

> Longam habet codam, supra morem felium.
>
> Longiorem habet codam et solito more felium.
>
> Longam habet codam. Ne feles quidem tantas habere codas solent.
>
> Nec qui ducentos annos in crypta habitabant tam pallidi videri solent.

Comment: Your answer from "Omnes fere...": might translate to "All who have presented approximate ways of saying 'even if it may be' have a different-agreement presentation, in a small way (as I have said), even if a surprise may have been given "this cat has a long tail"  more than "this cat has a longer tail than these cats (already having long tails!)". This is clearly incorrect. Please advise.

Comment: @tony The translation is actually quite different:  "Almost all the above sentences...have a somewhat different 'concessive' force (as it were), as if it were strange that 'this cat has a long tale' rather than that 'this cat has a longer tale than other cats--which already have long tales.' "